# google play alpha and beta tester function

Tags: android, apk, beta-testing

I have a question regarding the new **Play Developer Console functions** (Alpha & Beta Testing) , maybe somebody has some experience with it.

I invited some testers by GoogleGroups and they are receiving the invitation and can accept it.

I want to test a paid app. Do they have to pay for testing? this app is unpublished in the store yet but.

I have doubts to set it to free and later I cannot change to paid app.

any suggestions how to proceed?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to our tests, the brand new beta testing mechanism allows the beta testers to see in Google Play the beta version that you have published instead of the production version.
But the payment is not affected: If the app is a paid one, beta testers will have to pay for it, beta or not.
In other words, beta testers don't get a paid app for free.

So if you want to distribute the app without them paying, then you should distribute it outside of Google Play (email the apk for instance).

Beware that if you use Android Licensing API to protect your app, then you'll need to add the beta testers emails in the list of test accounts in the Google Play console > settings > Gmail accounts with testing access.

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted to know. As well I can make them pay and refund the amount afterwards

Comment: Yes you can have them pay and refund them. However, if you use licensing API, then you'll have to add them in the list of testers as I mentioned. This is because as soon as you refund them, they loose their license.

Comment: I had same confusion earlier... clear now, but one more query Let's say i am uploading my "Alpha/Beta" APKs and at that time can i set "Price" value to "$0.00"... and when I move from "Beta" to "Production" release at that time will change price value to original price... This will help to eliminate "Refund" process

Comment: @AnkitShah AFAIK that's not possible, once free, always free, regardless of alpha, beta or prod status. What were they thinking when decided this, don't know.

Comment: @muslidrikk if an app wasn't published yet, can it still be tested with in-app-billing? also, what's the difference between beta and alpha in the developer console?

Comment: Using the Android Licensing API is a must to protect your app, especially considering how easy it is to implement.  With that said, if you were to add an email to the "test accounts" section, how long does it take to update on Google's end?

Comment: @androiddeveloper In order to Test In APP billing: I can tell You my experience You MUST have the App published at beta version. Install exactly THAT version and then You can purchase items (for real or as TEST). I always use the beta version for testing. After purchasing I uninstall the App and continue working with the eclipse version (not signed, but item purchased)

Comment: @user1616685 this is such an annoying way to test IAP. :( Why couldn't google make it easier...

Comment: For paid app, what should I say to my testers?  paid me first before HELPing me to test my app

Comment: @muslidrikk that's not cool and not fair. Google shouldn't care about any paiment unless the app is in production.

Comment: Google wants more money, even if from beta testers.

Comment: Don't use Android Licencing API you will waste your time. Use In-App Billing and make your app freemium. And thank me.