# Android Alpha, Beta for Paid Apps on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

**What about "Paid Apps" as Alpha/Beta testing...**

I am uploading one "alpha_version" apk under "Alpha" tab... I have tagged application as "Paid" app and also configured specific prices... (As Google does not allows to change from "Free" to "Paid"). I have also added "Tester" for this alpha version..

**My Questions/Confusion:**

> 1. As my application is "Paid" one - do my "tester group" needs to pay before downloading this "alpha" version
> 2. Can I set application mode as "Free" for "Alpha" and latter on make is "Paid" for Production build?
> 3. Once I publish this "alpha" version - does it view-able/visible on Google Play store (I am sure it will be for visible for tester only
>      not for all users - right?)

Any help/pointer would be greatly appreciated - Thank You.

Comment: Check below link... It clears/helps for above confusion

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621527/google-play-alpha-and-beta-tester-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a paid app be tested in alpha/beta for free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975746/can-a-paid-app-be-tested-in-alpha-beta-for-free)

Answer (score 10):

1. AFAIK all users of a paid app, will need to pay for it. So also Alpha/Beta users. If you want them to test the app without paying for it, then you can distribute the app through e-mail or web, etc... without using the Play Store
2. NO. You also can't change a free app to a paid app in a later stage.
3. yes, but only test users will get the alpha/beta version.

If you want users to test your app for free in the Play store and sell your app to the general public, then you could distribute your app in an obfuscated name with irrelevant description for free for testers, and the real app, with the real name/description etc will be paid

Comment: 3. is wrong: even testers won't be able to find it searching for it, you have to give them the full url

Comment: @Lohoris I had to be more clear I think: What I meant to say was that if your app is published on the app-store(non beta/alpha version), then all users see it, but only alpha/beta testers get the alpha/beta version.

Comment: ok, then you might edit the answer accordingly, so that it's obvious to everyone! : )

Comment: For paid app, what should I say to my testers?  paid me first before HELPing me to test my app
sending apk by email is not a good solution, not saying the security, as user needs to go to option to enable the unknown source first. come on ... google

Comment: Moreover if your app has Google Play License Check you can't just redistribute it using emails.

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying but you could just create another app in your developer console that is free and load your APK there.  You will have to change the package name though and maybe give it a test name.  Keep this free app in beta and then they can test it for free.

Then when you want to release it you create a new app that is paid and release that.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352421/5916188

Yes, you can use a promo code to give beta testers (and others) a free copy at install time.