# Can a paid app be tested in alpha/beta for free

Tags: android, google-play

I've looked on SO at a lot of questions regarding this, and they all seem to say that if the app is a paid app, then Alpha and Beta testers will also have to pay to test it.

However, I'm naively hoping that as 99% of the answers I read are from mid 2013 when the Alpha/Beta testing feature first came out, that maybe Google have listened to people and changed this since then.

If not, what are my alternatives? I see them as the following

1. I presume I can refund people out of my own pocket but that means Google will keep their 30% so it'll cost me 30% of my app cost for each tester.
2. I could email them all the apk, but that way I'll have to do it for every update, rather than letting the play store do it for me. Also, if I have a lot of testers it could be annoying sending out multiple emails (unless I do one huge BCC of course)
3. Could I somehow set up two versions of the app in the store, one called free and one called paid. Only give the free version out to the testers, and then delete that app, and push the final apk to the paid app.

I think 3. is the best option, but more hassle than I'd expect from this presumably very common occurrence.

On a side note, who could I contact over this question, directly at Google? Someone at the play store team? How do you even find an address for that!?

UPDATE: When I do this now, I create promo codes and give them to my individual beta testers. It doesn't take more than 20secs per person, so for my number of people I'm good with that

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've had the same problem and contacted the google support, the result was: If you want to let your testers test the app for free, you have to create a free clone of the paid app.

You can find the full question and answer below.

Question:

> Is it possible to offer a paid app for free to alpha/beta test users
>   without creating a free clone of the app?

Answer:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer support about Beta
>   Testing. Please note that once you've set the price of an application,
>   you can change it at any time. However, once you’ve published an
>   application for free, you cannot change it to be priced at a later
>   time. Currently, this means Alpha and Beta versions will have to be at
>   least $0.99 if you want to charge for the app when it goes to
>   Production. Alpha/Beta testers will be charged for this amount. We do
>   this to prevent users who download a free app from being charged
>   during future updates or failing a licensing check when running the
>   app.
>
> If you'd like to sell an application that was previously published as
>   free, you'll need to upload a new APK and add a price. While you will
>   be unable to upload the same package name again, you will be able to
>   upload a slight variation on the original package name. As an
>   alternative, you may also implement in-app billing for your free app.
>
> We hope this helps answer your question. If we can assist you further,
>   please let us know.
>
> Regards, ... Google Play Developer Support

**Update:**
You can use promo codes to allow testers to access your paid app for free:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html

Comment: Thanks, I've created myself two apps on google play, one free and one paid, I'm currently using the free one with my beta testers, though I will never push that one to see the light of day, so when it's all good, I will push that code to the paid app.

Comment: Thanks for the link to promo code! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 15):

The answer is that, yes, you can allow beta testers to test a paid app without paying, but it requires you to create a new Promo in the Developer Console, with one promo code for each beta tester.

So if, for example, you expect to have not more than 10 beta testers that you will ask to test your app (without paying for it), then you would create a new promo with 10 codes, and provide one code to each of your testers.

Don't forget to include a code for yourself, too, so you can install the program/test it on your own device for free (without having to do so via ADB).

Comment: This answer is a good addition to the already good accepted answer, now that promo codes are available

Answer (score 2):

You can email them a promo code to download the app for free even from the alpha or beta channels.

It is available in the Google play console under user acquisition ... Promotion

Answer (score 1):

No. I think you've miss interpreted [the docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html).

For example, if you use In-App-Billing

You can make `test purchases` without any charge to the user.

or

You can use a real payment method to test with, but google stops the transaction going through, and you will receive a refund notification after 14 days.

I've developed paid apps. Google does not keep 30% from purchases during your testing.

Comment: But aren't you talking about In-App-Billing? I'm talking about buying the actual app, not things from within the app.

Comment: I've looked at the following SO questions and they all appear to say the same thing...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605780/google-play-developer-console-beta-test-paid-apps-for-free?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229972/android-alpha-beta-for-paid-apps-on-google-play-developer-console?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227301/how-do-i-allow-android-app-alpha-beta-testers-to-download-the-app-for-free?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Given the date on the initial post, Google may have updated this.

You don't have to pay as a tester but this is not clear until you have already clicked the instal option.  Then it will tell you that this is a test transaction and you will not be charged.

Comment: Mostly not true: If you’re testing a paid app using an open or closed test, testers still need to purchase it.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Play Console, you can now use [the Internal Test Track to let max 100 users test your paid app for free](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

- Those users will need to be identified by their Google account email, so this does not help if you need open (beta) testing

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Promo in the Developer Console, with one promo code for each beta tester. 
Give one code for one tester. Tester will open https://play.google.com/store?code and put here code. Now he have free app.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an alternative to doing this without generating promo codes. However it does give the testers access to all apps distributed by your developer account.

Go to the Google Play Console where you see the list of all of your apps. On the left go to Settings. Under "License Testing" enter the accounts that you want to have access. This will also allow those accounts to test IAPs.